# Rxjs.Observable.while not found in npm package

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

Is observable.while available in the main rxjs npm package?

I can't seem to find it included.

Is there another way to do asynchronous while loops?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`takeWhile`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeWhile) and a [`skipWhile`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-skipWhile) maybe one of those is what you are looking for? Other than that you'd have to be more specific what you mean by *"asynchronous while loops"*.